# Javascript frameworks used on server side to extend Javascript core?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, node.js

There are a lot of frameworks for the frontend:

- jQuery
- Prototype
- Mootools
- YUI
- ExtJS
- Dojo

Could these be used on the server side to extend Javascript native classes for example:

```
object2 = object1.clone();
```

And is this a good way of extending Javascript?

Cause I don't want to create every basic function I need but lacks from Javascript core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Underscore](http://github.com/documentcloud/underscore) might work for you.

checkout [this](http://github.com/ry/node/wiki/modules#commonjs-compat) list of Node modules.

Answer (score 2):

MooTools gives a special server oriented version of its library :
http://mootools.net/download/get/mootools-1.2.5-core-server.js

All functions related to the browser aren't include in this package. Since the purpose of this framework is to enhance javascript natives objects and not only focus on DOM handling and widgets things, this is a good choice.